# Remove project folder from website URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, url-rewriting, project-structure

I have a c# website project in visual studio 2010, and all of my .aspx pages are currently being stored in a `~/Forms directory`. The problem is that when I want to go to any web pages, they are all prefixed with `"http://localhost:000/Forms/"`, when what I really want is `"http://localhost:000/"`. So, `"http://localhost:000/AboutUs.aspx"` instead of `"http://localhost:000/Forms/AboutUs.aspx"`. What is the preferred way to deal with a situation like this? I don't want to rig anything up. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uh..., don't put your aspx files in a subdirectory maybe?

Comment: Ideally, I don't want (potentially) hundreds of pages off the root directory for the sake of organization.

Comment: GoatBreeder: What I do is create subdirectories for related files. For example, I have a shareware site that allows author submissions and have an Authors subdirectory. It makes sense for these pages to have a URL like www.domain.com/Authors/whatever.aspx. But your general-purpose pages should be in the root directory, and your directory layout should match your URL layout. Yes, there are exceptions to this with URL routing, but I don't see this as a valid use of URL routing. It adds unnecessary overhead, and makes it harder to know where pages are located.

Comment: After some consideration, I think this will be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your question while trying to find a solution to my own problem.

You can change the path of a website in visual studio by right clicking on the website project, going to "property window", and then setting the virtual path to whatever for instance, you can set it to "/".

If your issue here was just gettinng absolute URLs to work in your test enviroment, this should be enough.